# Reading annotations defined on interfaces and create bean classes using annotation values

Tags: spring, spring-boot, annotations

I am trying to create http client on the fly from jaxrs annotations provided on the interface for each api.

```
public @interface RestClient {
  String baseUrlKey();  
}


@Component
@RestClient(baseUrlKey="NOTIFICATION")
@Path("/notification/")
public interface NotificationClient {
    @Path("/")
    @POST
    @Produces("application/json")
    @Consumes("application/json")
    public abstract NotificationResponse create(NotificationEntry entry);

}
```

Now, I am trying to write another class which is trying to find all interfaces annotated with @RestClient. I cant seem to find any solution for this. All application context methods seem to return classes which can be instantiated. Is there any way I can load this interface and create bean instance of apache http client on the fly and register with application context.

Here is the bean initializer class -

```
public class RestClientBeanProcessor {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(RestClientBeanProcessor.class);

    @Autowired
    RestTemplate restTemplate;

    @Autowired
        ApplicationContext applicationContext;


    @PostConstruct
    private void registerClientBeans() {
        Map<String, Object> beans = applicationContext.getBeansWithAnnotation(RestClient.class);
        LOGGER.info("Registering client beans for - " + beans);
    }

}
```

My beans object is empty. Spring is unable to tell me list of interfaces asked by my query.

Comment: Need to use java reflection hence you can get the value which has an annotation marked, in this case your NotificationClient is a component so this will keep its values because RestClientBeanProcessor class wants to get values of interface beans after this has an instance by PostConstructor. So you should be able to get values before enters NotificationClient interface

Comment: Not possible with spring context at all? Ideally there should be some util ?